# Redis: only persist non-expiring keys, please?

Tags: io, redis, memcached, persistence, database-performance

From what I'm seeing in the docs, it appears that Redis only lets you persist all keys, or don't persist at all (to disk).

What I'm trying to do is to only persist keys that don't have a TTL. That is, if I

```
setex some_key 60 "some data"

// or

set some_key "some data"
expire some_key 60
```

then don't persist those keys to disk -- ever!

In case this is not possible, I guess the next best solution is to use Memcached for those values, and Redis for what I'd like persisted, but it'd sure be nice if I don't have to go that far..

Comment: Whats the issue if you persist all keys as if you have specified TTL those keys will anyhow expire from disk. You can also use volatile-lru or volatile-ttl options Redis will discard only those keys that have an expiration when it runs out of memory..

Comment: Problem is that we only care about persisting a small percentage of our keys. So whenever Redis persists all those keys with ttls, it really puts a lot of stress on the server. Since this happens every 60 seconds, we'd like to only persist the keys we need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK What you are telling is correct it can either persist on can not persist. However, in this scenario Instead of using Memcache I would run two instance of redis one which can persist the keys and one with no persistence. As Creating the redis instance is easy.

Also, In future if there is a situation where you need few keys to be persist you can make the changes easily at application level if you use redis instead of Memcache.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case. Thanks.